# How to use onchange event on selectize in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, selectize.js

I use selectize as select option in vue, but I can not trigger onchange event on selectize, how I can do it? this is my code

```
<selectize v-model="input.city" data-placeholder="City" required @change="test">
   <option :value="data.id" v-for="(d, i) in cities" :key="i"> {{d.name}} </option>
</selectize>
```

and in vue methods this is my code,

```
test(){
   alert("it's work");
}
```

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Watchers` in vue to trigger value change:

```
watch: {
  'input.city': function(value) {
    console.log('city changed');
  }
}
```

More detail: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: watch: {
  'input.city': (value) => {
    console.log('city changed');
  }
}

it's work! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you used [vue2-selectize](https://github.com/rhyek/vue2-selectize/blob/master/src/main.vue), if yes, you can try code below, as this vue component emits an input event while changing selection:

```
<selectize v-model="input.city" data-placeholder="City" required @input="test">
   <option :value="data.id" v-for="(d, i) in cities" :key="i"> {{d.name}} </option>
</selectize>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@input` works for me.

```
<selectize data-placeholder="City" required @input="test">
   <option :value="data.id" v-for="(d, i) in cities" :key="i"> {{d.name}} </option>
</selectize>
```

```
test(value){
   this.input.city = value;
   alert("it's work");
}
```